# Recompiling C# DLL for closed source program

Tags: c#, .net, dll

I have decompiled one of the DLL files that a closed source program uses and want to make edits to it. Is it possible for me to recompile just the DLL file even though it has errors due to it referencing other files obviously not included in my project.

Thanks.

Comment: The obvious question: have you tried it?  Should take far less time to attempt than to ask here.

Comment: If you aren't using classes that reference those other dlls - I'm assuming that you aren't because you don't have the other dlls - then just create a new dll with only the classes that you are using.

Answer (score 3):

> Is it possible for me to recompile just the DLL file even though it has errors due to it referencing other files obviously not included in my project.

In general, no.  You'll need to have the other assemblies in order to reference them in your project.

Also, be careful that you're not violating the original software's license terms by decompiling.  Many non-open source projects have licenses which explicitly disallow any reverse engineering or modification.

Answer (score 0):

> it has errors due to it referencing other files

Can you build any other project which has errors in it? The answer is **NO**.

You should only de-compile the code you own. As you don't want to use your efforts without paying you, similarly respect others effort. Had they wanted to show you code they would have given you.